# Fetching mails to openerp inbox for every user in openerp7

Tags: odoo

I know that there is a way to define incoming mail gateway. If we configure it and click on fetch now we will get all mails in the Administrators inbox. Is there a way to configure this for every user and so when every user logs in he/she will get their mails in their openerp inbox itself.  Kindly help me to do that with openerp7. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create incoming mail servers for every users via Settings->Techincal->Incoming Mail Server providing Username and Password of every users in the Login Information table!

Comment: Thanks floyd, As you say, i can create multiple records in Incoming mail server, but does that bring the mails in each user's inbox. Kindly clarify me. Thank You

Comment: No, creating records does not bring mails in each user's inbox. Only OpenERP users that supply their email address and password to the Configuration of each Incoming mail servers can fetch the unread messages in their inbox and will appear in the Messaging Module.